# Check my work on Shafarevich, section 3, problem 4

Tags: algebraic-geometry

The problem is to find the irreducible components of the affine variety $X=Z(y^2=xz, z^2=y^3)$ over an algebraically closed field $\mathbb{k}$ and show that each component is birational to $\mathbb{A}^1$.

My work:  if $y=0$ or $z=0$ then $x$ can take any value and both $y$ and $z$ must be zero.
Otherwise both $y$ and $z$ are not zero so we have $$y^2=xz, z^2=y^3$$
iff (multiply equation $1$ by $\frac{y}{z}$ and substitute equation $2$ into equation $1$)$$z=xy, z^2=y^3$$ iff (substitute equation $1$ to equation $2$ and cancel $y^2$) $$z=xy, x^2=y$$ iff (substitute equation $2$ into equation $1$) $$z=x^3, y=x^2$$

So this all together this gives $X = Z(y,z) \cup Z(z-x^3, y-x^2)$.  Both of these sets are isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1$ and hence irreducible and birational to $\mathbb{A}^1$.

The reason I am concerned is because I don't understand why the problem would ask us to show that the irreducible components are birational to $\mathbb{A}^1$ if they are in fact isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1$ (which is stronger).

Comment: Don't be worry about the formulation of the problem : your computations and results are  perfect. Bravo and +1.

Comment: Thanks!  I feel better now.

Comment: Yes, I think I understand what you felt and I wanted to reassure you. Good luck with the study of our beautiful subject, algebraic geometry.

Comment: As Georges said, this is a great solution. I just wanted to point out an alternative way to find the irreducible components. The second relation can be written $z^2 - y \cdot xz = 0$, or rather $z(z - xy) = 0$. So one collection of irreducible components have $z = 0$ and the other collection have $z = xy$. Now looking at the first relation we get that the first collection is $\{(z, y)\}$ and the second collection $\{(z-xy, y-x^2)\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question answered in comments.